# Android. OkHttp cookies are not saved after relaunching the app

Tags: android, okhttp

I use the following code to setup cookies

```
PersistentCookieJar cookieJar = new PersistentCookieJar(
                new SetCookieCache(), new SharedPrefsCookiePersistor(context));
        clientBuilder.cookieJar(cookieJar);
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(
                clientBuilder.build()).build();
```

This is the header I received from server:

```
Set-Cookie: wordpress_logged_in_6041590398a33ab947560d559f09d479=capad%7C1488467742%7CSttfNHrOkwd67CteCGepJyv3bNU2SeSW0URepOPxCe5%7C5091b3bbcc334e520cec85c4c9b8e26a07a962d3c00c8c709b87f90018370f60; path=/; secure; httponly
```

Comment: What do the cookies look like?

Comment: Just posted the header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cookie (`Set-Cookie: wordpress_logged_in_[etc]; path=/; secure; httponly`) has no expiration set.

This makes it a "session" cookie, which should not be persisted. Your `PersistentCookieJar` likely follows the correct spec in not persisting any cookies without an expiration.

You can either manually add on an expiration when you receive this cookie (perhaps with an OkHttp interceptor), or create your own version of the `PersistentCookieJar` that persists all cookies (this is probably not a good idea).

Another option would be to respect the fact that whoever is sending that cookie wants it to be a session cookie.